# GoJs render part of a template conditionally

Tags: javascript, angular, gojs

I would like to render a part of a template depending of a node data object item value

If value is `true` I would render this template part

```
$(go.TextBlock, { row: 1, column: 0, font: '12px \'Open Sans\'', margin: 3, stroke: '#707070' }, $localize`:@@step-view-4: Paramètres:`),
$(go.TextBlock, { row: 1, column: 1, font: '12px \'Open Sans\'', margin: 3, stroke: '#707070' }, new go.Binding('text', 'Apple')),
$(go.TextBlock, { row: 2, column: 0, font: '12px \'Open Sans\'', margin: 3, stroke: '#707070' }, 'Input:'),
$(go.TextBlock, { row: 2, column: 1, font: '12px \'Open Sans\'', margin: 3, stroke: '#707070' }, new go.Binding('text', 'InputValue')),
```

if not I would render:

```
$(go.TextBlock, { row: 1, column: 0, font: '12px \'Open Sans\'', margin: 3, stroke: '#707070' }, $localize`:@@step-view-4: Banana:`),
$(go.TextBlock, { row: 1, column: 1, font: '12px \'Open Sans\'', margin: 3, stroke: '#707070' }, new go.Binding('text', 'BananaValue')),
```

I have a first solution is to render two different templates depending on item value

But I would like to use only one template.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap template into a Panel and bind to GraphObject's property "**visible**" with a convertion function.
See: [GoJS API - Class Binding](https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Binding.html)

For example (not tested, just schematic):

```
var displTempl = true;

$( go.Panel, {},

    $(go.TextBlock,
        {row: 2,column: 0,font: "12px 'Open Sans'",margin: 3,stroke: "#707070"},
        "Input:"
    ),
    $(go.TextBlock,
        { row: 2, column: 1, font: "12px 'Open Sans'", margin: 3, stroke: "#707070" },
        new go.Binding("text", "InputValue")
    ),
    new go.Binding("visible", false, (obj) => {
        return this.displTempl;
    })
)
```